# How to simplify this rational form?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Please, someone can help me to rewrite this complex expresion

$\frac{c^2 k n q \left| k\right|  \left(c k^2 \kappa _T-i h \omega  \left| k\right| \right)}{-i c k^2 \left| k\right|  \left(c^2 m \omega ^2 \left(h \eta _e+G \kappa _T\right)-T \kappa _T \left(c^2 k^2+\omega ^2\right)\right)+\omega  \left| k\right| ^2 \left(T \left(\alpha _V \left(h \omega ^2-c^2 k^2\right)+c^2 (h+1) k^2+c^2 k^2 \alpha _T \left(\alpha _V-1\right)\right)-c^2 G h m \omega ^2\right)+c^4 k^4 m \omega  \eta _e \kappa _T}$

simply in the form : $ A+i B$   $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(i^2=-1$)

Mathematica input:

```
 (c^2 k  Abs[k] n q (-I h \[Omega] Abs[k]+c k^2 Subscript[\[Kappa], T]))/(\[Omega] Abs[k]^2 (-c^2 G h \[Omega]^2 m+T (c^2 (1+h) k^2+c^2 k^2 Subscript[\[Alpha], T] (-1+Subscript[\[Alpha], V])+(-c^2 k^2+h \[Omega]^2) Subscript[\[Alpha], V]))+c^4 k^4 \[Omega] m Subscript[\[Eta], e] Subscript[\[Kappa], T]-I c k^2 Abs[k] (-(c^2 k^2+\[Omega]^2) T Subscript[\[Kappa], T]+c^2 \[Omega]^2 m (h Subscript[\[Eta], e]+G Subscript[\[Kappa], T])))
```

Thank's

Comment: Use `ComplexExpand[]`.

Comment: You nee to indicate which of your variables are complex in the second argument to [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call your expression `expr`. Then simplify with:

```
{a, b} = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[ReIm[expr]]]
```

The real part is in the variable `a` and the imaginary part is in the variable `b`.